# Matplotlib "LinearSegmentedColormap" error

Tags: matplotlib, data-science, jupyter

Can someone help me with this error of matplotlib?
I'm using jupyter for some data science project from a famous book (hands-on machine learning...) but I have a problem with an unusual error.

This is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude", alpha=0.4,
             s=housing["population"]/100, label="population", figsize=(10,7),
             c="median_house_value", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), colorbar=True,
             sharex=False)
plt.legend()
save_fig("housing_prices_scatterplot")
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [85], line 3
      1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 3 housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude", alpha=0.4,
      4              s=housing["population"]/100, label="population", figsize=(10,7),
      5              c="median_house_value", cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet"), colorbar=True,
      6              sharex=False)
      7 plt.legend()
      8 save_fig("housing_prices_scatterplot")

File ~/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py:945, in PlotAccessor.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    943 if kind in self._dataframe_kinds:
    944     if isinstance(data, ABCDataFrame):
--> 945         return plot_backend.plot(data, x=x, y=y, kind=kind, **kwargs)
    946     else:
    947         raise ValueError(f"plot kind {kind} can only be used for data frames")

File ~/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py:71, in plot(data, kind, **kwargs)
     69         kwargs["ax"] = getattr(ax, "left_ax", ax)
     70 plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
---> 71 plot_obj.generate()
     72 plot_obj.draw()
     73 return plot_obj.result

File ~/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:452, in MPLPlot.generate(self)
    450 self._compute_plot_data()
    451 self._setup_subplots()
--> 452 self._make_plot()
    453 self._add_table()
    454 self._make_legend()

File ~/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:1225, in ScatterPlot._make_plot(self)
   1223 if self.colormap is not None:
   1224     if mpl_ge_3_6_0():
-> 1225         cmap = mpl.colormaps[self.colormap]
   1226     else:
   1227         cmap = self.plt.cm.get_cmap(self.colormap)

File ~/my_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py:87, in ColormapRegistry.__getitem__(self, item)
     85 def __getitem__(self, item):
     86     try:
---> 87         return self._cmaps[item].copy()
     88     except KeyError:
     89         raise KeyError(f"{item!r} is not a known colormap name") from None

TypeError: unhashable type: 'LinearSegmentedColormap'
```

I just want to use matplotlib for a simple and normal graph but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Apparently the `.plot()` method expects a colormap **NAME** and not a colormap INSTANCE

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing in `cmap=plt.get_cmap("jet")` just pass in `"jet"`.

So the call should instead be

```
%matplotlib inline  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude", alpha=0.4,
             s=housing["population"]/100, label="population", figsize=(10,7),
             c="median_house_value", cmap="jet", colorbar=True,
             sharex=False)
plt.legend()
save_fig("housing_prices_scatterplot")
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet.

this is the value error:

ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not median_house_value

Comment: What version of python, matplotlib and pandas are you using? Everything works as expected for me with python 3.10 (book recommends using 3.8), pandas 1.5.1, matplotlib 3.6.1

Comment: I'm going through the same book as the OP and indeed passing the string totally worked. I'm going to guess matplotlib changed the API here in some recent version?

Answer (score 1):

A plot was made without error after I deleted this: cmap=plt.get_camp("jet"). The color range was default, not from blue to red.

Comment: tried the original code on my ipad using the APP called Carnets plus, and it works just fine. so this error is likely due to using Windows for me. not sure if you are using Windows too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the colormap argument instead of cmap and pass in the colormap name:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
housing.plot(kind="scatter", x="longitude", y="latitude", alpha=0.4,
             s=housing["population"]/100, label="population", figsize=(10,7),
             c="median_house_value", colormap="jet", colorbar=True,
             sharex=False)
plt.legend()
save_fig("housing_prices_scatterplot")
```